# select maximum Consecutive Records

Tags: mysql

i have table in following format

```
-------------
| id | item |
-------------
|1   | xxx  |
|1   | xxx  |
|1   | yyy  |
|1   | xxx  |
|1   | zzz  |
|1   | xxx  |
|1   | xxx  |
|1   | xxx  |
|1   | yyy  |
|1   | xxx  |
|1   | yyy  |
|1   | xxx  |
|1   | xxx  |
|1   | xxx  |
|1   | xxx  |
|1   | xxx  |
|1   | xxx  |
|-----------|
```

I need to count maximum consecutive value of the item xxx.
The above example its 6.

Thank you

Comment: What defines their order? Until you specify any order criteria it's not possible to talk about ordered set

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @last = NULL, @max = 0, @count = 0;

SELECT   @count := IF(item = @last, @count + 1, 0),
         @max   := GREATEST(@max, @count + 1),
         @last  := item
FROM     my_table
ORDER BY ...

SELECT @max;

SET @last = NULL, @max = NULL, @count = NULL;
```